# Jar linking issue in Scala

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, jar

**What i do:**

1.I am running a scala project,When i added the java source code(java file) in to the project it run

2.I need to add the jar file the project instead of the java source file

3.So i created jar file for the java source file in eclipse and added the jar file in the scala project instead of the java source file

4.But it shows error,when calling the method in the jar file

5.When i added the jar which i created in the java project,it works

**Things i need to know:**

1.Is there any different ways to add jar(created in java)  in the scala project?

2.Whether i need to create jar in any other way?

Comment: You don't need to create the jar differently - Scala uses the exact same jar format as Java. When you say "added the jar file in the scala project", can you give more details (how)?

Comment: @Tzach Zohar,thanks for you reply
1.i am using scala IDE
2.Right click on the project,Properties->JavaBuildPath->Libraries
3.click on Add External jar and choose the jar

Comment: Well, I'm not too familiar with Eclipse, but sounds like changing JavaBuildPath to compile _Scala_ doesn't make sense... look for a ScalaBuildPath?

Comment: All the jar files for the project are added in JavaBuildPath only,i searched for ScalaBuildPath but nothing like that.